# AngularFire2 initializing app gives error

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

I am trying to initialize AngularFire2 in my Angular2 application, but I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/firebase/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/jaruesink/Documents/Projects/buckets/src/app/firebase/index.ts (16,17): Return type of exported function has or is using name 'ModuleWithProviders' from external module "/Users/jaruesink/Documents/Projects/buckets/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module" but cannot be named.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (/Users/jaruesink/Documents/Projects/buckets/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:115:15)
    at /Users/jaruesink/Documents/Projects/buckets/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:140:17
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 15:0-48
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

Here is my Firebase module that I am trying to import as initializeFirebase() in my NgModule.

```
import { AngularFireModule, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  FIREBASE STUFF GOES HERE
};

export const firebaseAuthConfig = {
  provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
  method: AuthMethods.Redirect
}

export function initializeFirebase() {
  return AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, firebaseAuthConfig);
}
```

Can someone help explain what I am doing wrong, or if something else is going on, is there a way I can work around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not work when placed in the external file has to do with this function:

```
export function initializeFirebase() {
  return AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, firebaseAuthConfig);
}
```

The declaration does not specify a return type, so it's inferred to be `ModuleWithProviders` - the return type of `initializeApp` (and the type that's mentioned in the error).

To solve the problem, you can specify the return type, which will also mean you need to add an import:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
...
export function initializeFirebase(): ModuleWithProviders {
  return AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, firebaseAuthConfig);
}
```

For more information, see this GitHub [issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9944#issuecomment-244448079)

Answer (score 0):

I placed all the config stuff into the same file as the NgModule and then it worked... I had separated it like this before and it worked, but I guess not this time.