# error TS4058: Return type of exported function has or is using name X from external module Y but cannot be named

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

> Using tsc v2.2.2

How to fix typescript compiler error:

> error TS4058: Return type of exported function has or is using name
>   '{SomeInterface}' from external module
>   "{some path}/dist/types"
>   but cannot be named.

I have folder with **index.ts** and **something.ts**

```
// index.ts
import something from './something'

// error will point on this export below
export default function () {
   return {
     resultFunctionFrom: something()
   };
}


// something.ts
import {ICoolInterface} from 'some-module'

export default function () {
  return function (rootOfEvil:ICoolInterface) {
     // ...
  };
}
```

I will get this error with such code:

> error TS4058: Return type of exported function has or is using name
>   'ICoolInterface' from external module
>   "/folder/node_modules/some-module/dist/types"
>   but cannot be named.

Comment: `ICoolInterface` is used in the inferred return type of the default export, but `ICoolInterface` is not exported. Adding `export ICoolInterface` should solve your problem. For more info: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8612

Comment: @cartant no, I tried to add export {ICoolInterface} without success. Still have error even with export.

Comment: I've solved this before, but my recollection is a bit dodgy, I guess. It could be that you need to be explicit with the return type: `export default function (): (coolInterface: ICoolInterface) => void /* or whatever the return type is */ { ... }` - rather than letting it be inferred.

Comment: Likely related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41137419/6680611

Comment: @cartant for me return type :any for default export in 'index.ts' did the trick. And no need to export ICoolInterface. Maybe it's a bad practice to use :any like this but at least it compiles and my function in 'something.ts' described well with arg types and return types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** This should no longer happen in TypeScript 2.9 and resolves Issue 9944 linked below.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#relaxing-declaration-emit-visiblity-rules

Currently you need to explicitly import `ICoolInterface` in `index.ts`:

```
// index.ts
import {ICoolInterface} from 'some-module'
```

Consider tracking this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9944) where they are considering changing this TypeScript behaviour.

> There is no explicit type annotation on the functions or variables.
>   the declaration emitter infers their type and tries to write it. if
>   the type is coming from a different module, then a. it needs to add an
>   import or b. error.
>
> The emitter can write the additional import, but that would have been
>   changing your API shape in a way you did not indicate clearly in your
>   code. so we opted to error instead.
>
> the fix would be to add an explicit type annotation on the source of
>   the problem.
>
> Having siad that, i think we should reconsider this design decision,
>   and add imports anyways.

Note: if you are using WebStorm, you will be warned about an unused import. You can disable the warning with the comment `//noinspection ES6UnusedImports` above the import. GUI alternative: press `Alt + Enter` on the import line with the warning. Right arrow for more options on `Remove unused 'import'` popup menu and choose `Suppress for statement` to disable the warning on this particular line.

Answer (score 10):

For me return type :any for default export in 'index.ts' did the trick. And no need to export ICoolInterface. Maybe it's a bad practice to use :any like this but at least it compiles and my function in 'something.ts' described well with arg types and return types.
So this will work:

```
// index.ts
import something from './something'

// error will point on this export below
// ------------------------\/-----------
export default function ():any { // trouble solver
// ------------------------/\-----------
   return {
     resultFunctionFrom: something()
   };
}


// something.ts
import {ICoolInterface} from 'some-module'

export default function () {
  return function (rootOfEvil:ICoolInterface) {
     // ...
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved - error TS2305: Module has no exported member

Answer (score 0):

i met the same problem today

//useAutpSelecChart.ts

```
import {ref} from 'vue'
import type {Ref} from 'vue'
import type {Echarts} from 'echarts'

//Return type of exported function has or is using name 'ECActionEvent' from external module but cannot be named

export default function useAutoSelectChart(){
  const echartRef = ref<ECharts | null>(null)
  return {
    echartRef
  }
}
```

my solution is declare a new type

```
type EchartRef=Ref<Echarts|null>
```

and use it like

```
const echartRef:EchartRef=ref()
```